# spring local-sensitive data

Tags: spring, internationalization, spring-mvc, resourcebundle

I have some problems with making my web-app adapted for remote user browseres language settings. 
I used ResourceBundleMessageSource for it. It looks like this:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="resources/messages" /> </bean>
```

And I have two .properties files:

- messages.properties
- messages_ru.properties

They are located in src/resources/messages.

I want to configure my app such way, that when remote users browser language settings contain russian, my app should use russian messages (messages_ru), otherwise (if language is not configured or it's not russian), it should use meessages.properties (it contains english messages).

When I setup russian in my browser, it works fine. When I erase all settings, it's also shows russian (I think it depends on system locale settings). And when I set some another language, it also show me russian messages.

Only way to make my app to show english messages is to rename messages.properties to messages_en.properties and set in browser english lang. But I want to make my app adopted for all language settings (when it use russian, if it needs, and english for any other settings and any other countries).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set

```
<bean id="messageSource" 
     class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">  
    <property name="basename" value="resources/messages" />
    <property name="fallbackToSystemLocale" value="false" />
</bean>
```

In this case Spring will use `messages.properties` as a fallback, so it should contain messages in the "default" locale for your application.

Comment: ResourceBundleMessageSource doesn't have a fallbackToSystemLocale property. I've also tried to use ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource, which contain this property. But specification says: "Falling back to the system Locale is the default behavior of java.util.ResourceBundle. However, this is often not desirable in an application server environment, where the system Locale is not relevant to the application at all: Set this flag to "false" in such a scenario.".

Comment: And my try also not recieve a results. Now when browser configured into Russian, it shows russian messages, otherwise it shows an error, that file messages_(name of language) (e.g. messages_de) doesn't exist.

Comment: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'welcome.title' for locale 'ru_RU'.

Comment: Where should I put my messages.properties and messages_ru.properties file?

Comment: Location of your properties files corresponds to the `basename` property. In webapp you usually write `<property name = "basename" value = "/WEB-INF/messages" />` and store you files as `/WEB-INF/messages.properties`, `/WEB-INF/messages_ru.properties`, etc.

Comment: Yeah... I find out problem. I use spring security. So, only login.jsp page located outside WEB-INF folder. My messages.properties file is located in WEB-INF deirectory. So, when I launch my app, it couldn't get the properties file.